# Implementing a Google's OAuth2 process setting a redirect URI with # in it

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to implement Google's OAuth2 process in Java:

```
// Load client secrets.
InputStream in = Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
    clientSecrets,
    Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS)
)
    .setAccessType("offline")
    .build();

String uri = flow
    .newAuthorizationUrl()
    .setRedirectUri("http://example.com/#/oauth2callback")
    .build();
```

Once the `uri` string is created, I'll try to navigate to it, hoping after authentication process I'll be redirected to `http://example.com/#/oauth2callback`. But Google prompts an error saying:

```
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Fragment not allowed
```

Which means I can not use a `#` in my redirect URI (as far as I know). Is there any way around it? How can I set a redirect URI with a `#` in it?